# Writing dynamic double linked list with a sentinel and struct type in C

Tags: c, struct

I was trying to create that list by using example from "Introduction to Algorithms (3rd Edition)". But I experienced some difficulties which I cannot understand. Firstly, the work of the program is changing due to existence of printf function in precise place. There is one place which needs printf and a lot of other places which can't have printf. Secondly, value of L.nil.next changes after every line of code which does something referred to struct. Unfortunately, because of that changing value I cannot fix the program. I would be very pleased if someone fixed and forced it to work like dynamic double linked list with a sentinel.

There is a code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

struct sentinel{
    struct listel* nil;
};

struct listel{
    struct listel* prev;
    int key;
    struct listel* next;
};

int list_search(struct sentinel *L, int k);
void list_insert(struct sentinel *L, struct listel *x);
void list_delete(struct sentinel *L, struct listel *x);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int s;
    struct sentinel *L=(struct sentinel*)malloc(sizeof(struct sentinel));
    printf("---sentinel created\n"); //FORCED TO WRITE
//  printf("L.nil = %p\nL.nil.prev = %p\nL.nil.next = %p\n", L->nil, L->nil->prev, L->nil->next);
    L->nil->next=L->nil;
    L->nil->prev=L->nil;
//  printf("sentinel parameters set\n"); //NOT ALLOWED TO WRITE
//  printf("L.nil = %p\nL.nil.prev = %p\nL.nil.next = %p\n", L->nil, L->nil->prev, L->nil->next); //NOW ALLOWED TO WRITE
    struct listel *x=(struct listel*)malloc(sizeof(struct listel));
    printf("created x\n");
//  printf("L.nil.next=%p\n", L->nil->next); //NOT ALLOWED TO WRITE
//  printf("prev = %p\nkey = %d\nnext = %p\n", x->prev, x->key, x->next); //NOW ALLOWED TO WRITE
    struct listel *y=(struct listel*)malloc(sizeof(struct listel));
    printf("created y\n");
//  printf("L.nil.next=%p\n", L->nil->next); //NOT ALLOWED TO WRITE
    struct listel *z=(struct listel*)malloc(sizeof(struct listel));
    printf("created z\n");
//  printf("L.nil.next=%p\n", L->nil->next); //NOT ALLOWED TO WRITE
    x->key=8;
//  printf("x.key = %d is set\n", x->key); //NOT ALLOWED TO WRITE
//  printf("L.nil.next=%p\n", L->nil->next); //NOT ALLOWED TO WRITE
//  x->next=L->nil->next;   //Trying to check line from list_insert without using that function
//  printf("x.next=L.nil.next=%p\n", x->next); //NOT ALLOWED TO WRITE
    list_insert(L, x); //I have checked no further
    x->key=3;
    list_insert(L, y);
    x->key=4;
    list_insert(L, z);
    printf("%d\n", list_search(L, 8));
    printf("%d\n", list_search(L, 6));
    printf("%d\n", list_search(L, 3));
    return 0;
}

int list_search(struct sentinel *L, int k){
    struct listel *x=(struct listel*)malloc(sizeof(struct listel));
    x = L->nil->next;
    while (x!=L->nil && x->key!=k) x=x->next;
    if (x==L->nil) return 0;
    return (x->key);
}

void list_insert(struct sentinel *L, struct listel *x){
    printf("    LIST INSERT\n");
//  printf("    L.nil.next=%p\n", L->nil->next);
    x->next=L->nil->next;
//  printf("    x.next=L.nil.next=%p\n", x->next); //NOT ALLOWED TO WRITE - I have checked no further
    L->nil->next->prev=x;
    L->nil->next=x;
    x->prev=L->nil;
}

void list_delete(struct sentinel *L, struct listel *x){
    x->prev->next=x->next;
    x->next->prev=x->prev;
}
```

Comment: in `L->nil->next=L->nil;` - `L->nil` is *indeterminate* at this point, so dereferencing it invokes *undefined behavior*. Only three lines in and I stopped reading after that.

Comment: ^^^^^^^ run under debugger and fix the glaring bugs.

Comment: When you find your program changes behaviour because you move `printf()` statements around, or add them or remove them, then you almost invariably have memory access problems.  If it is available for your platform (e.g. not on macOS Sierra, though it is on Mac OS X), then the [Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/) tool is excellent for spotting misdeeds with dynamically allocated memory.  Used carefully (basically, make sure you compile with debugging information — usually `-g`), it usually identifies where you are abusing memory.

Answer (score 1):

malloc does not initialise the allocated memory to anything sensible, so

```
struct sentinel *L=(struct sentinel*)malloc(sizeof(struct sentinel));
printf( ... L->nil,   L->nil->prev ... UNDEFINED!! CRASH!! );
L->nil->next=L->nil; // UNDEFINED!! CRASH!!
L->nil->prev=L->nil; // UNDEFINED!! CRASH!!
```

Delete all this and start with:

```
struct sentinel *L=(struct sentinel*)malloc(sizeof(struct sentinel));
L->nil = NULL;
```

You should be able to see that L->nil->prev and L->nil->next are meaningless unless L actually contains a valid list element, e.g. if you did this:

```
struct listel *x=(struct listel*)malloc(sizeof(struct listel));
x->prev = NULL;
x->next = NULL;
L->nil = x;
```

then L->nil->prev == x->prev == NULL and L->nil->next == x->next == NULL

Comment: I assume this is supposed to be a circular list with a sentinel node, similar to C++ std::list. The sentinel node is the same as the other nodes, so it would use struct listel, not struct sentinel.  When initializing an empty list, `L->next = L` and `L->prev = L` .

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, it's working with a circular double linked list with a sentinel node. This is how C++ std::list is usually implemented.

Use a typedef to simplify the code. This syntax is "legacy" compatible:

```
typedef struct listel_{
    struct listel_* next;
    struct listel_* prev;
    int key;
}listel;
```

A sentinel node is the same as a regular node, and should use the same struct, in this case listel. Example code to initialize a sentinel node to represent an empty list by setting the sentinel node's next (first node) pointer and previous (last node) pointer to point to the sentinel node.

```
listel *L
/* ... */
    /* allocate and initialize a sentinel node */
    L = (listel *)malloc(sizeof(listel));  
    L->next = L;        /* pointer to first node of list */
    L->prev = L;        /* pointer to last  node of list */
```

list_insert should take a key as input and allocate a node internally (no need for x, y, z):

```
void list_insert(listel *L, int k);
```

list_delete should take a key as input and delete a node internally.

```
void list_insert(listel *L, int k);
```

list_search should not allocate a node, it works with an existing list. Normally list_search would return a pointer to node if found or NULL if not found.

```
listel * list_search(listel *L, int k);
```

Working example with added display function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct listel_{
    struct listel_* next;
    struct listel_* prev;
    int key;
}listel;

void     list_display(listel *L);
listel * list_search(listel *L, int k);
void     list_insert(listel *L, int k);
void     list_delete(listel *L, int k);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    listel *L;
    /* allocate sentinel node */
    L =(listel *)malloc(sizeof(listel));
    L->next = L;
    L->prev = L;

    /* display list while inserting 3 nodes */
    list_display(L);
    list_insert(L, 8);
    list_display(L);
    list_insert(L, 3);
    list_display(L);
    list_insert(L, 4);
    list_display(L);

    /* display search list results */
    printf("%d %d\n", (list_search(L, 8) != NULL) ? 8 : 0, 8);
    printf("%d %d\n", (list_search(L, 6) != NULL) ? 6 : 0, 6);
    printf("%d %d\n", (list_search(L, 3) != NULL) ? 3 : 0, 3);
    printf("\n");

    /* display list while deleting 3 nodes */
    list_display(L);
    list_delete(L, 3);
    list_display(L);
    list_delete(L, 8);
    list_display(L);
    list_delete(L, 4);
    list_display(L);

    /* free sentinel node */
    free(L);
    return 0;
}

void list_display(listel *L)
{
listel *e;
    if(L == NULL || L->next == L)       /* if list empty */
        return;                         /*  return */
    e = L->next;                        /* display list forward */
    do{
        printf("%d  ", e->key);
        e = e->next;
    }while(e != L);
    printf("\n");
    e = L->prev;                        /* display list backward */
    do{
        printf("%d  ", e->key);
        e = e->prev;
    }while(e != L);
    printf("\n\n");
}

listel* list_search(listel *L, int k){
listel *e;
    if(L == NULL || L->next == L)       /* if list empty */
        return NULL;                    /*  return null */
    e = L->next;
    while (e != L && e->key != k) e=e->next;
    if (e == L)                         /* if not found */
        return NULL;                    /*  return null */
    return e;
}

void list_insert(listel *L, int k){
listel *e;
    if(L == NULL)                       /* if no sentinel node */
        return;                         /*  return */
    e = (listel *)malloc(sizeof(listel));
    if(e == NULL)                       /* if can't allocate node */
        return;                         /*  return */
    e->next = L->next;                  /* e->next = first node */
    e->prev = L;                        /* e->prev = sentinel */
    e->key  = k;
    L->next->prev = e;
    L->next = e;
}

void list_delete(listel *L, int k){
listel *e;
    if(L == NULL || L->next == L)       /* if list empty */
        return;                         /*  return */
    e = L->next;
    while (e != L && e->key != k) e=e->next;
    if (e == L)                         /* if not found */
        return;                         /*  return null */
    e->prev->next = e->next;            /* remove node from list */
    e->next->prev = e->prev;
    free(e);                            /* free node */
}
```

Comment: I would be grateful if you could add it.

Comment: @Mr.White - I updated my answer with example code, including a display function.